# Base64 sting which is encoded tiff image is not able to get the Bitmap in android

Tags: android, tiff, google-code, libtiff

I have `Base64` string which is `.TIFF` formatted image encoded.
Trying to decode and getting the bitmap in Android, but getting the null bitmap.
Following is the code which i am using to get the bitmap

```
val imageBytes = Base64.decode(base64EncodedTiffImageStr, Base64.DEFAULT)
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size)
```

I am expecting bitmap of tiff image with above code

Comment: Bitmap cannot decode a tiff image as far as i know. You could just try it with a tiff file to see.